# Get N'th line of multiple files in linux

Tags: linux, csv, awk, sed, echo

The task I'm trying to accomplish is, I have this kind of files:

test1.csv test2.csv test3.csv etc...

And I want to get 3'rd line of every file. Right now, I can get 3'rd lines using awk, or sed like

`echo |  awk 'FNR == 3 { print; exit }' test1.csv >> last_file.csv` or using sed or tail.

But when I try to do this on multiple files, It cannot get the lines. I want to do like this,

`echo |  awk 'FNR == 3 { print; exit }' test*.csv >> last_file.csv`

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give input and the output you are getting?

Comment: You mean, output if I try it on multiple files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Get rid of the useless `echo`, the incorrect `exit` and the redundant `print`:

```
awk 'FNR == 3' test*.csv
```

Comment: Thank you, this one is even better.

Comment: @mau5 This is actually less efficient because it processes the whole file, where as the nextfile command allows us to skip to the next file once we have gotten the line we want.

Comment: Efficiency is something to be addressed when necessary, no point cluttering up a script off the bat with performance improvements that'll make it less concise and non-portable when it will almost certainly run in the blink of an eye as-is for the OPs real files (when people have unusually large files to process they invariably tell us that) and if performance IS an issue then we can discuss options and tradeoffs.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations, I appreciate. For my task, the file contains only 3 or 4 lines. But, if someone had a pretty big file, I hope they'd consider 'nextfile' as answer. Sorry to make confusion, I should've mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -sn 3p test*.csv >> last_file.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
awk 'FNR == 3 { print; nextfile }' test*.csv >> last_file.csv
```

The problem is that when you use `exit`, it stops awk from processing input completely. The `nextfile` tells awk to stop processing the current file and go to the next file. The `echo` command as you are using it is not necessary.

Read more here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in all files in directories and it's sub-directories and so on.

```
shopt -s globstar
awk 'FNR == 3' **/test*.csv
```